# lfs 6.41 XMLParser undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_attr_getstacksize@@GLIBC_2.2.5'

Tags: linux, linux-from-scratch

I have an issue while building LFS system,

I'm at point 6.41 and I'm building XML:Parser

I'm making 
perl Makefile.PL
make
make test

and then I got

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tools/lib/perl5/5.30.0/x86_64-linux/auto/threads/threads.a(threads.o): undefined         reference to symbol 'pthread_attr_getstacksize@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
/usr/bin/ld: /lib/libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [Makefile.aperl:1095: perl] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/sources/XML-Parser-2.44'
make: *** [Makefile:928: perl] Error 2
```

Have you an idea of how I can fix that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've fix it adding -lpthread to /mnt/lfs/sources/XML-Parser-2.44/Expat/Makefile.PL

on the line

my $libs = "-lexpat -lpthread";